# TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE and TAR_ENTRY_INVALID when trying to npm install any package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json, tar

I tried to delete `npm_cache` and install the latest version of `npm`, but it didn't work. I have no additional ideas because I searched all the similar questions with the same error. I can't even `npm install`, though global installations work. This error is only present within this project. Installations in other projects on my machine work as usual.

```
npm install axios
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm ERR! code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm ERR! TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-14T22_59_28_705Z-debug.log
```

Here is what it logs when I try `npm install axios -verbose`.

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'axios'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.5.4
2 info using node@v15.0.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
19 verbose npm-session 2948ad5d93d129dc
20 timing npm:load Completed in 33ms
21 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 2ms
22 timing idealTree:init Completed in 1806ms
23 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 9ms
24 silly idealTree buildDeps
25 silly fetch manifest homepage@https://xyz.github.io/ecommerce
26 warn tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
27 silly tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure {
27 silly tar   header: Header {
27 silly tar     cksumValid: false,
27 silly tar     needPax: false,
27 silly tar     nullBlock: false,
27 silly tar     block: null,
27 silly tar     path: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
27 silly tar       '<html lang="en">\n' +
27 silly tar       '  <head>\n' +
27 silly tar       '    <meta charset="utf-8" />\n' +
27 silly tar       '    <meta name="viewport" con',
27 silly tar     mode: null,
27 silly tar     uid: null,
27 silly tar     gid: null,
27 silly tar     size: null,
27 silly tar     mtime: null,
27 silly tar     cksum: null,
27 silly tar     linkpath: '     name="description"\n' +
27 silly tar       '      content="Web site created using create-react-app"\n' +
27 silly tar       '    />\n' +
27 silly tar       '    <link\n' +
27 silly tar       '   ',
27 silly tar     uname: null,
27 silly tar     gname: null,
27 silly tar     devmaj: 0,
27 silly tar     devmin: 0,
27 silly tar     atime: null,
27 silly tar     ctime: null,
27 silly tar     [Symbol(type)]: ' '
27 silly tar   },
27 silly tar   cwd: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\b7842840',
27 silly tar   code: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID',
27 silly tar   tarCode: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID'
27 silly tar }
28 warn tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
29 silly tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure {
29 silly tar   header: Header {
29 silly tar     cksumValid: false,
29 silly tar     needPax: false,
29 silly tar     nullBlock: false,
29 silly tar     block: null,
29 silly tar     path: ' type="image/png"\n' +
29 silly tar       '      sizes="16x16"\n' +
29 silly tar       '      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-16x16.png"\n' +
29 silly tar       '    />\n' +
29 silly tar       '    <link r',
29 silly tar     mode: null,
29 silly tar     uid: null,
29 silly tar     gid: null,
29 silly tar     size: null,
29 silly tar     mtime: null,
29 silly tar     cksum: null,
29 silly tar     linkpath: 'mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />\n' +
29 silly tar       '    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor"',
29 silly tar     uname: null,
29 silly tar     gname: null,
29 silly tar     devmaj: 0,
29 silly tar     devmin: 0,
29 silly tar     atime: null,
29 silly tar     ctime: null,
29 silly tar     [Symbol(type)]: '"'
29 silly tar   },
29 silly tar   cwd: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\b7842840',
29 silly tar   code: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID',
29 silly tar   tarCode: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID'
29 silly tar }
30 warn tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
31 silly tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure {
31 silly tar   header: Header {
31 silly tar     cksumValid: false,
31 silly tar     needPax: false,
31 silly tar     nullBlock: false,
31 silly tar     block: null,
31 silly tar     path: 'pp-manifest/\n' +
31 silly tar       '    -->\n' +
31 silly tar       '    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />\n' +
31 silly tar       '    <!--\n' +
31 silly tar       '      No',
31 silly tar     mode: null,
31 silly tar     uid: null,
31 silly tar     gid: null,
31 silly tar     size: null,
31 silly tar     mtime: null,
31 silly tar     cksum: null,
31 silly tar     linkpath: 'will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.\n' +
31 silly tar       '      Only files inside the `',
31 silly tar     uname: null,
31 silly tar     gname: null,
31 silly tar     devmaj: 0,
31 silly tar     devmin: 0,
31 silly tar     atime: null,
31 silly tar     ctime: null,
31 silly tar     [Symbol(type)]: ' '
31 silly tar   },
31 silly tar   cwd: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\b7842840',
31 silly tar   code: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID',
31 silly tar   tarCode: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID'
31 silly tar }
32 warn tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
33 silly tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure {
33 silly tar   header: Header {
33 silly tar     cksumValid: false,
33 silly tar     needPax: false,
33 silly tar     nullBlock: false,
33 silly tar     block: null,
33 silly tar     path: ' by running `npm run build`.\n' +
33 silly tar       '    -->\n' +
33 silly tar       '    <link\n' +
33 silly tar       '      rel="stylesheet"\n' +
33 silly tar       '      href="https://maxcdn.boo',
33 silly tar     mode: null,
33 silly tar     uid: null,
33 silly tar     gid: null,
33 silly tar     size: 4,
33 silly tar     mtime: null,
33 silly tar     cksum: null,
33 silly tar     linkpath: '  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"\n' +
33 silly tar       '      crossori',
33 silly tar     uname: null,
33 silly tar     gname: null,
33 silly tar     devmaj: 0,
33 silly tar     devmin: 0,
33 silly tar     atime: null,
33 silly tar     ctime: null,
33 silly tar     [Symbol(type)]: ' '
33 silly tar   },
33 silly tar   cwd: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\b7842840',
33 silly tar   code: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID',
33 silly tar   tarCode: 'TAR_ENTRY_INVALID'
33 silly tar }
34 warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
35 silly tar Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
35 silly tar     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\warn-mixin.js:19:40)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\unpack.js:189:18)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:81:14)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.emit (node:events:339:22)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.[emit] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:285:12)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.[maybeEnd] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:401:17)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:432:21)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.write (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:364:25)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.end (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:477:14)
35 silly tar     at Yallist.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass\index.js:396:18)
35 silly tar  Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
35 silly tar     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\warn-mixin.js:19:40)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\unpack.js:189:18)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:81:14)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.emit (node:events:339:22)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.[emit] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:285:12)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.[maybeEnd] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:401:17)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:432:21)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.write (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:364:25)
35 silly tar     at Unpack.end (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:477:14)
35 silly tar     at Yallist.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass\index.js:396:18) {
35 silly tar   recoverable: false,
35 silly tar   cwd: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\b7842840',
35 silly tar   code: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE',
35 silly tar   tarCode: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE'
35 silly tar }
36 http fetch GET 200 https://xyz.github.io/ecommerce/ 2815ms
37 silly fetch manifest axios@*
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios 178ms
39 silly placeDep ROOT axios@0.21.1 OK for: ecommerce@0.1.0 want: *
40 silly placeDep ROOT homepage@ OK for: ecommerce@0.1.0 want: https://xyz.github.io/ecommerce
41 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 3124ms
42 timing idealTree:node_modules/axios Completed in 0ms
43 timing idealTree:node_modules/homepage Completed in 0ms
44 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 3127ms
45 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 23ms
46 timing idealTree Completed in 4968ms
47 timing command:install Completed in 5002ms
48 verbose stack Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\warn-mixin.js:19:40)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\unpack.js:189:18)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:81:14)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.emit (node:events:339:22)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.[emit] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:285:12)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.[maybeEnd] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:401:17)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:432:21)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.write (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:364:25)
48 verbose stack     at Unpack.end (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:477:14)
48 verbose stack     at Yallist.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass\index.js:396:18)
49 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce
50 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
51 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "axios"
52 verbose node v15.0.0
53 verbose npm  v7.5.4
54 error code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
55 error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
56 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Does this error occur if you do a fresh clone of the project? Have you tried removing and reinstalling `node_modules` in the project? Have you tried `npm cache verify` and/or `npm cache clean --force`? Does this occur with any package or just axios?

Comment: I tried cleaning cache, also now I deleted node_modules and this error occurs when I hit npm install so now I can't even install node_modules

Comment: What's in the debug log? Is it the same as the --verbose output?

Comment: Have you tried [`npm doctor`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-doctor)?

Comment: I reinstalled whole node and this error is no more there, Now I have error while deploying react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I tried to reinstall Node and error was gone. Also try cleaning cache before it.

Comment: my `npm install` doesn't work after  I reinstall the Node and clean the cache. It shows below:`npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm ERR! code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm ERR! TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format`  No idea what to do now.  Can Someone help?

Answer (score 2):

when I remove the **homepage** from the **package.json** it workes fine.

Comment: This worked for me, after also removing the `proxy` from `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an unexpected version format or value lands inside a `package.json` file. Validate if your `package.json` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Before I started having this issue, I added a key to my `package.json` file
named `homepage` and the value is the domain name of my website. I just removed it and everything worked fine. So if you're experiencing similar issue and you've uninstalled and reinstalled node, cleared cached and the issue persists. I'd advise you verify the `package.json` file